# Response object in spring microservice cqrs

Tags: spring, cqrs

I am writing login endpoint in spring microservice cqrs. But how can I get the data of the user object and token from the command to respond to the client?

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<?> login (@RequestBody LoginRequestDto body) {
    try {
        LoginCommand loginCommand = LoginCommand.builder()
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .email(body.getEmail())
                .password(body.getPassword())
                .build();
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(loginCommand);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( , HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Can respond to the client with user data and tokens